# Tridion ECL Implementation

Tags: sdl-tridion, ecl

I need to work on implementing ECL to integrate external assets to tridion. I have gone through few documents. Can you please help on working example of ECL (which has working external service endpoint), so that i can implement end to end. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the [video](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7) in the documentation as well as download an [API example](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF) to get started with the External Content Library.

Also find the Flickr [ECL provider on the SDL Appstore](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/flickr-ecl-provider/629/), noting the comments about using "https." Credit for the video to @Lars and Flickr examples to @Bart.